# How to create a row of stars with turtle

Tags: python

My code for making a single star is:

```
t = turtle.Turtle()

for i in range(5):
    t.forward(150)
    t.right(144)
```

That gives me one star, so how would I make a row of them?

Comment: How would you do it if you had to describe it step by step in English?

Answer (score 0):

Add another loop for the number of stars you want in a row, `forward(150)` to the new star start point

Example to have a row of 3 stars

```py
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()

for j in range(3):
    for i in range(5):
        t.forward(150)
        t.right(144)
    t.forward(150)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice not to use variables where they're not needed.

```
def star_row(x, n)
    for _ in range(n):
        for _ in range(5):
            t.forward(150)
            t.right(144)
        t.forward(x)
```

This will make a row of `n` length of stars separated by `x` pixels